# Como hacer un UPDATE genérico con java

Tags: java

estoy intentando desarrollar una pequeña aplicación, que me permita actualizar cualquier tabla de cualquier BD de mi servidor local. Cuando arranco la aplicación, tengo dos ComboBox, uno de ellos se llena con todas las BDs que hay en mi servidor y el otro se llena a partir de seleccionar la BD del primer comboBox y los datos de la tabla se vuelcan en un **JTable**. He conseguido insertar, con un **JDialog dinámico**, pero no consigo montar mi consulta UPDATE para poder actualizar, ya que los SET serán variables. Tengo que decir, que he conseguido montar el SET y mostrar por pantalla por medio de un **System.out.println()** los nombres de las columnas, pero no consigo montar el resto de la consulta. Adjunto mi código actual, a ver si me podéis echar una mano. Gracias por adelantado.

```
modelo.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            String campos = "";
            String seleccion = "";
            Object[][] datosCampos = new Object[50][50];
            int filaSeleccionada = jtTablaResultados.getSelectedRow();
            int columnaSeleccionada = jtTablaResultados.getSelectedColumn();

            for(int i=0; i<modelo.getColumnCount(); i++){
                seleccion = (String)modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, columnaSeleccionada);
                campos += " " + modelo.getColumnName(i) + "=";                    
            }


            for(int i=0; i<modelo.getRowCount(); i++){
                int j=0;
                for(; j<jtTablaResultados.getColumnCount();j++){
                    datosCampos[i][j] = modelo.getValueAt(i, j);
                    //System.out.println("salida: " + datosCampos[i][j]);
                }
                String consulta = "UPDATE " + (String)jcTablas.getSelectedItem() + " SET " + campos;
                System.out.println(consulta);
            }

        }
    });
```

Tengo que decir, que para actualizar lo necesito para cuando la tabla cambie, por eso está dentro de un tableChanged.

He probado a crear una matriz y volcar los datos ahí y efectivamente, al recorrer la matriz los datos estaban, pero no se componer mi consulta...

**Actualización**

Salida en el System.out.println();

```
fff: UPDATE articulos SET  idArt=null nombre=null existencias=555 ppu=null idPro=null
```

**Actualizacion 2**
[image: GUI y salida]

**Actualización 3**

Código funcional y que sirve para cualquier actualización de cualquier tabla

```
modelo.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {

        @Override
        public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
            String campos = "";
            String seleccion = "";
            int filaSeleccionada = jtTablaResultados.getSelectedRow();
            int columnaSeleccionada = jtTablaResultados.getSelectedColumn();

            for (int i = 0; i < modelo.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                seleccion = String.valueOf(modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, i));
                campos += " " + modelo.getColumnName(i) + "=" + "'"+seleccion+"'" + ",";
            }

            int idSeleccionado = (int)modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, 0);

            String consulta = "UPDATE " + (String) jcTablas.getSelectedItem() + " SET" + campos + " WHERE " + modelo.getColumnName(0) + "=" + idSeleccionado;

            consulta = consulta.substring(0, consulta.length() - 15) + " WHERE " + modelo.getColumnName(0) + "=" + idSeleccionado;;

            System.out.println(consulta);

            mysql.ejecutaConsultaAccion(consulta);
        }

    });
```

El subString era para quitar la última coma antes del WHERE

Comment: Puede agregar un ejemplo de lo que imprime `System.out.println(consulta)`

Comment: @E.Betanzos mil gracias por su respuesta. en mi pregunta he añadido lo que me dice

Comment: Lo que me parece es que la tabla donde debes agregar los valores que vas a actualizar en la base de datos, no las has terminado de llenar. Lo digo porque hay campos en la consulta que si tienen datos y otros son `null`. Ej. `nombre=null existencias=555`

Comment: todos tienen datos @E.Betanzos, lo que pretendo es capturar los datos que ya hay + el que yo cambie o añada, he puesto un ejemplo de una tabla en la que el campo existencias estaba vacío y yo he agregado eso. Pero lo que quiero es que en el campo idArt aparezca el id del articulo, nombre=nombre, existencias=existencias y así para todos los productos en este caso. Pero no consigo capturar los que hay + el que yo introduzca o cambie, no se si me explico

Comment: Puedes agregar una imagen de tu GUI donde aparezca dicha tabla??

Comment: listo @E.Betanzos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes que nada considero que el segundo ciclo `for` sobra al igual que la matriz `datosCampos`.

Creo que el problema que tienes es porque en el primer ciclo `for` solo concatenas a la variable `campos` y el símbolo `=`, pero no el valor de la celda, que por demás si lo obtienes y almacena en la variable `seleccion`. Este código debe solucionar ese problema.

```
modelo.addTableModelListener(new TableModelListener() {
    @Override
    public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
        String campos = "";
        String seleccion = "";
        int filaSeleccionada = jtTablaResultados.getSelectedRow();

        for(int i=0; i<modelo.getColumnCount(); i++){
            seleccion = (String)modelo.getValueAt(filaSeleccionada, i);
            campos += " " + modelo.getColumnName(i) + "=" + seleccion;                    
        }

        String consulta = "UPDATE " + (String)jcTablas.getSelectedItem() + " SET " + campos;
    }
});
```

Ahora, el código anterior solo te permite crear una consulta dinámica que incluya los valores de cada campo según la tabla que muestra por pantalla. Pero no creo que te funcione ejecutar la consulta en la base de datos, porque no tienes en cuenta los tipos de datos de los campos. Por ejemplo, el campo `nombre` me dice el sentido común que debe ser de un tipo que permita almacenar cadenas de caracter (algún tipo de varchar, o similar) y en la consulta le defines el valor a modificar como si fuera un campo numérico: `nombre=valor`. Esto fallará claramente en la base de datos, ya que debería definirse de este modo: `nombre='valor'` (notar las comillas simples).

Por lo anterior considero que tu solución es incompleta. Trata de diseñar algún mecanismo que te permita determinar dinámicamente el tipo de dato de cada campo de la tabla en la base de datos, y en función de estos tipos, construyas la consulta adecuadamente.

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, he probado su código y solo me muestra después del igual lo que yo modifico, es decir si yo mofifico existencias=555 me marca todos los campos con 555. Antes de meterme con la función que calcule los tipo de datos de cada columna, estoy tratando de montar la consulta para saber como se hace, puesto que es relativamente complicado y no tenía claro como hacerlo. De nuevo gracias

Comment: Si, tienes razón, es que olvidé utilizar la `i` como índice de la columna de la cual deseo conocer su valor. Ya lo corregí.

Comment: mil gracias @E. Betazos efectivamente era eso. Ahora haré mi método para hacer el casting de los datos.

Comment: Perfecto, por nada!!

Comment: Betazos no ha hecho falta ni crear un método para extraer los campos de la BD, lo he hecho con un Update pasandolo a todos los SET sus '' y ha funcionado perfectamente. Adjunto código

Comment: ¿Y con los campos numéricos funciona también?

Comment: Betazos, si perfectametne, al entre comillarlos, se lo traga perfectamente, hay que tener en cuenta que es MySQL

Comment: Pues que interesante, hoy aprendí algo nuevo!! Saludos.